# DataSet и сохранение в БД

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, ado.net

Подскажите пожалуйста.

У меня есть `DataSet` заполненный данными из .csv файла, как сохранить эти данные в БД. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Конструктивная критика приветствуется.

```
private DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

private void buttonReadCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV|*csv", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dataSet.Tables.Add(ReaderCSV.Read(ofd));
            modelEnterDataBindingSource.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}

public static DataTable Read(OpenFileDialog ofd)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open));
    CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr);
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource.DataSource = csv.GetRecords<ModelEnterData>().ToList();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    IEnumerable<ModelEnterData> models = bindingSource.DataSource as IEnumerable<ModelEnterData>;
    using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(models))
    {
        dataTable.Load(reader);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: `StreamReader` и `FileStream` нужно освобождать так же, как `OpenFileDialog` и `ObjectReader`. То есть используйте `using` (или `Dispose`).

Comment: Зачем в этом коде `BindingSource`? Уберите его. / Раз уж вы используете `DataTable`, то для записи в БД можно применить `DataAdapter` или `TableAdapter`.

Comment: Спасибо, учту замечания. Все же хочу узнать как сохранить эти данные.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже правильно в комментариях сказали, можно использовать DataAdapter, у которого нужно будет вызвать метод [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx) (по ссылке еще и пример есть). Для обновления он использует команды, которые сгенерируются по умолчанию [CommandBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)'ом, но никто не мешает определить и свои.

```
static private DataSet CreateCommandAndUpdate(
    string connectionString,
    string queryString)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter =
            new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder =
            new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        // Code to modify data in the DataSet here.

        // Without the SqlCommandBuilder, this line would fail.
        adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
        adapter.Update(dataSet);
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```